# can awk be used to strip both a leading white space and trailing empty line

Tags: unix, awk

I have an output file `file.out` that looks like this: (leading white space per line) and a trailing empty line.

**file.out:**

```
 abc
 def
 ghi
 jkl
 *whitespace*
```

So far, i'm able to do this - `awk '{$1=$1};1' file.out` to trim the leading space.

Can `awk` strip the empty line/whitespace?

Comment: Sure. I think it's `NF == 0 { next; }`. I guess you could just change the existing logic to  `NF { $1 = $1 } ...`

Comment: combine it with `awk '{$1=$1};1' file.out`?

Comment: It'd have to be `awk 'NF { $1=$1; print }' file.out` because the `1` just prints every single line.

Comment: perfect! that works for me. if you'd like to post your answer, i can accept that. appreciate the help

Comment: It should be @shawnt00's answer, I think.

Comment: With `sed`: `sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//;/^$/d' file`.

Comment: if the lines are more then one word use : `awk 'NF&&gsub(/^ */,"")' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your current logic to test for fields before outputting the row:

```
NF { $1 = $1; print }
```

Comment: golf to `NF{$1=$1}1`